# pointer segmentation fault at scanf

Tags: c, pointers, memory, segmentation-fault

a Little help?
I'm pretty sure the answer must be something silly, but I cannot see why am I getting a segmentation fault right after my scanf. I've been staring at my piece of code for a long time now:

```
#include<stdio.h> 
#include<stdlib.h> 
#include<string.h> 

typedef struct Student{ 

    int grade, id; 
    struct Student *next; 
}student; 


student *initialize(){
    return NULL;
}

int main(){ 
    student *init; 
    student *nxt; 
    student *actual;
    int resp;

    init = (student*)malloc(sizeof(student)); 
    init = initialize();

    actual = init; 

    while(1){ 
        printf("type grade:\n"); 
        scanf("%d", &actual->grade); 
        printf("type id:\n"); 
        scanf("%d", &actual->id); 
        printf("wanna continue? (1-YES e <other>-NO)\n"); 
        if(resp==1){ 
            actual->next=(student*)malloc(sizeof(student)); 
            nxt=actual->next; 
        }else 
            break; 
    }

    actual->next=NULL;
    return 0; 
}
```

No big deal, right? There is a struct, I want to scan a value into it. on my terminal, I get:

```
type grade:
3
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

any ideas?

Comment: Try `scanf("%s", actual.grade)` instead

Comment: You set the value of init to NULL when you called initialize.

Comment: Why setting init to null after initialize, returning NULL...

Comment: There's another bug in there, using scanf and carriage returns...

Comment: Try using for() loops, instead of while(). It simplifies life!

Answer (score 2):

First you allocate memory for `init`

```
init = (student*)malloc(sizeof(student));
```

but you immediately set `init` to NULL with the return value of your `initialize()` function here

```
init = initialize();
```

Not only is this a memory leak, but you next set `actual` to NULL here

```
actual = init;
```

Then later in your while loop you dereference `actual` (which is NULL) in several places such as here

```
scanf("%d", &actual->grade);
```

Dereferencing NULL pointers is undefined behaviour and this is a likely source of your error.

Comment: Thank you! I saw that you should initialize your structure as null on a tutorial, I guess I did it on the wrong order.. Noobs right? haha  
I'm sorry about the dumb question, you guys are the best!

Comment: You should be aware that many 'tutorials' are full of crap.  Nulling a pointer/whatever just before loading it with another, valid value is pointless, (pointerless?), at best, and easy to get wrong at worst.  Same with the cargo-cult 'bzero/memset' of I/O buffers.

Answer (score 0):

Your initialize() function is returning null and you are creating a memory leak.  Instead of returning null initialize the data members to reasonable values.

Answer (score 0):

"Thank you! I saw that you should initialize your structure as null on a tutorial, I guess I did it on the wrong order.. Noobs right? haha I'm sorry about the dumb question, you guys are the best"

you are correct, you should initialize to null. But the code you have doesnt do that.

You need to do this

```
student *initialize(student * st)
{
   st->id = 0;
   st->grade = 0;
   st->next = NULL;
   return st;
}
```

or use calloc instead of malloc to make a student object (calloc clears the memry to 0)

or do

```
init = malloc ...
memset(init, 0, sizeof(student));
```